# Where do you put external directory authentication in a Ruby on Rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, coding-style, ldap

I'm going to implement RESTful user authentication against an LDAP directory in my Rails app using `net-ldap`. I've already verified that this works, but where do you put this in a Rails app? Does that go in some kind of helper? In my `UsersController`?

Here's an example of some authentication code:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'net/ldap'

ldap = Net::LDAP.new
ldap.encryption :simple_tls
ldap.host = 'directory.company.com'
ldap.port = 636
ldap.auth 'uid=human,ou=people,o=mycompany', 'turboSecret'

if ldap.bind
  puts 'win!'
else
  puts 'fail :('
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I put this in `app/controllers/sessions_controller.rb`.

## sessions_controller.rb

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController

  # Authenticate user against their LDAP directory
  # user and directory correspond to models in my app
  # password is a string
  # For complete source, see http://github.com/sidewaysmilk/auther
  def directory_login(user, password)

    directory = user.directory

    return nil if !directory

    directory.bind_dn['%s'] = user.login

    ldap = Net::LDAP.new
    ldap.host = directory.host
    ldap.port = directory.port
    ldap.encryption :simple_tls if directory.use_simple_tls?
    ldap.auth directory.bind_dn, password
    if ldap.bind
      return user 
    end
  end

end
```

Comment: I would recant this. This logic should be pushed down at least into the model, and possibly even into a separate lib that the model calls.